# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fpdf'

Tags: python, pyfpdf

Getting this error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fpdf'`

I've re-downloaded python, created a new venv and installed fpdf2 using `pip install fpdf2`, but I still get this error when I run `from fpdf import FPDF`

python version: 3.10.4

I've looked all over stack overflow and through the github issues and haven't found any solutions, and have no idea what to try next.

Comment: Did you activate your virtual env for the installation and actual run?

Comment: I created a virtual environment, activated it, installed fpdf2 with your command and successfully imported it with the same `from fpdf import FPDF`.

Answer (score 2):

firstly please make sure that you want `fpdf` or `fpdf2` lib, these are two different lib.

It seems that you want `fpdf`, so you need to try:

```
pip install fpdf
```

Comment: I want fpdf2, not fpdf, as fpdf is no longer maintained.

Answer (score 2):

I was using VSCode's Jupyter extension and it wasn't using the same virtual environment that the terminal was using - so the install wasn't going to the right place. Once I aligned the two virtual environments, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

This may be silly but should you be using fpdf2 instead of fpdf? Because if that's the name then it needs to be exact.

```
from fpdf2 import FPDF
```

Otherwise if you are using an IDE, then you may need to download the package into the IDE. For example in PyCharm I had to go to Python Packages and install it through there even after pip. Probably some path related issue.

Comment: The documentation says to import it just like fpdf: `from fpdf import FPDF`

I'm using VSCode, so I'll check into that - thanks